# Generating azure storage SAS token for client in java

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-blob-storage

For uploading media my client will send a request to the server:

```
message GetMediaUploadCredRequest {
  media.MediaType.Enum media_type = 1;
  media.Extension.Enum extension = 2;
  string file_name = 3;
  bool is_private = 4;
  string uploaded_by = 5;
}
```

And the server will generate a SAS token (like `presigned_url` from AWS) and `http_header` will send back to the client.

```
message GetMediaUploadCredResponse {
  string upload_credential_url = 1;
  map<string, string> https_headers = 2;
  string media_id = 3;
}
```

client will then make a PUT request to the URL with the `https_headers` and the upload process will be complete.

Here is the implementation:

```
public class StorexServiceImpl extends StorexServiceGrpc.StorexServiceImplBase {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StorexServiceImpl.class);

    private static final String STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING = "<connection-string>";
    
    private static final String CONTAINER_NAME = "<container-name>";



    @Override
    public void getMediaUploadCred(GetMediaUploadCredRequest request, StreamObserver<GetMediaUploadCredResponse> response) {
        try{
            MediaType.Enum mediaType = request.getMediaType();
            Extension.Enum extension = request.getExtension();
            
            String fileName = String.format("%s.%s", UUID.randomUUID(), extension.toString());

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING).buildClient();
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
            BlobHttpHeaders headers = new BlobHttpHeaders().setContentEncoding("gzip");

            BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setWritePermission(true); // Set the permission to allow uploading
            OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusHours(1); // Set the expiration time to 1 hour from now

            BlobServiceSasSignatureValues sasValues = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permission)
                    .setProtocol(SasProtocol.HTTPS_HTTP);

            String sasUrl = blobClient.generateSas(sasValues);

            Map<String, String> httpHeaders = new TreeMap<>();
            httpHeaders.put("Content-Type", getContentType(mediaType, extension));
            if(!request.getIsPrivate()) {
                httpHeaders.put("x-amz-acl", "public-read");
            }

            String blobId = blobClient.getBlobName(); // get the ID of the blob

            GetMediaUploadCredResponse res = GetMediaUploadCredResponse.newBuilder()
                    .setMediaId(blobId) // set the blob ID in the response
                    .setUploadCredentialUrl(sasUrl)
                    .putAllHttpsHeaders(httpHeaders)
                    .build();
            response.onNext(res);
            response.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e){}
        super.getMediaUploadCred(request, response);

    }

    private String getContentType(MediaType.Enum mediaType, Extension.Enum extension) {
        if(mediaType == MediaType.Enum.IMAGE) {
            return "image/" + extension.toString().toLowerCase();
        } else if(mediaType == MediaType.Enum.AUDIO) {
            return "audio/mp3";
        } else if(mediaType == MediaType.Enum.VIDEO) {
            return "audio/mp4";
        } else if(mediaType == MediaType.Enum.FILE) {
            return "application/" + extension.toString().toLowerCase();
        }
        return "binary/octet-stream";
    }
}
```

But for result I got this:

```
{
    "uploadCredentialUrl": "sv=2021-10-04&spr=https%2Chttp&se=2023-03-24T13%3A36%3A38Z&sr=b&sp=w&sig=JUXXe1Qi13VWipgFWzx70mTOsVqadQCjmIF%2BxRl14cs%3D",
    "httpsHeaders": {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "mediaId": "0ae4a0c5-167d-4a32-9752-0ad0d2b67e66.JPEG"
}
```

The uploadCredentialUrl seems weird and not like an actual URL at all.

**Update 1:**

Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135060/azure-blob-storage-java-generate-sas-token-always-throw-sr-is-mandatory-cannot). So I changed my code a bit:

```
    public void getMediaUploadCred(GetMediaUploadCredRequest request, StreamObserver<GetMediaUploadCredResponse> response) {
        try{
            MediaType.Enum mediaType = request.getMediaType();
            Extension.Enum extension = request.getExtension();

            String fileName = String.format("%s.%s", UUID.randomUUID(), extension.toString());

            
            log.info("New Implementations Started");
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(new Date());
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
            String start = fmt.format(cal.getTime());
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 4);
            String expiry =  fmt.format(cal.getTime());
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY), "HmacSHA256");
            Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
            String  resource ="sc";
            String permissions ="rwdlac";
            String service = "b";
            String apiVersion="2019-07-07";
            String stringToSign = STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME + "\n" +
                    permissions +"\n" +  // signed permissions
                    service+"\n" + // signed service
                    resource+"\n" + // signed resource type
                    start + "\n" + // signed start
                    expiry + "\n" + // signed expiry
                    "\n" +  // signed IP
                    "https\n";
            log.info("string to sign: {}", stringToSign);

            String signature=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256HMAC.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            String sasToken = "sv=" + apiVersion +
                    "&ss=" + service+
                    "&srt=" + resource+
                    "&sp=" +permissions+
                    "&se=" + URLEncoder.encode(expiry, "UTF-8") +
                    "&st=" + URLEncoder.encode(start, "UTF-8") +
                    "&spr=https" +
                    "&sig=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature,"UTF-8");
            log.info("sas token: {}", sasToken);
            String resourceUrl = "https://" + STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME + ".blob.core.windows.net/" + CONTAINER_NAME + "?comp=block&" + sasToken;
            
            

            Map<String, String> httpHeaders = new TreeMap<>();
            httpHeaders.put("Content-Type", getContentType(mediaType, extension));
            if(!request.getIsPrivate()) {
                httpHeaders.put("x-amz-acl", "public-read");
            }

            GetMediaUploadCredResponse res = GetMediaUploadCredResponse.newBuilder()
                    .setMediaId("blob id") // set the blob ID in the response
                    .setUploadCredentialUrl(resourceUrl)
                    .putAllHttpsHeaders(httpHeaders)
                    .build();
            response.onNext(res);
            response.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

And I got a response:

```
{
    "uploadCredentialUrl": "https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER_NAME>?comp=block&sv=2019-07-07&ss=b&srt=sc&sp=rwdlac&se=2023-03-28&st=2023-03-24&spr=https&sig=RpdV8prUgjzFApNo6bkuuiRAPHnw1mqww5l42cwVwyY%3D",
    "httpsHeaders": {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "mediaId": "blob id"
}
```

But when I tried this:

```
curl -X PUT -T ~/Downloads/gfx100s_sample_04_thum-1.jpg -H "x-ms-date: $(date -u)" "https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER_NAME>/myimage.jpg?comp=block&sv=2019-07-07&ss=b&srt=sc&sp=rwdlac&se=2023-03-28&st=2023-03-24&spr=https&sig=RpdV8prUgjzFApNo6bkuuiRAPHnw1mqww5l42cwVwyY%3D"
```

I got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:337c6e4d-301e-0019-7ebd-5f3baf000000
Time:2023-03-26T08:30:28.5705948Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was storageapollodevappstro
rwdlac
b
sc
2023-03-24
2023-03-28

https
2019-07-07
</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>%
```

**Update 2:**

I have updated my code following jccampanero guideline:

```
    @Override
    public void getMediaUploadCred(GetMediaUploadCredRequest request, StreamObserver<GetMediaUploadCredResponse> response) {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING).buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME);
        BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true).setWritePermission(true);
        OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(30);

        String blobName = containerClient.getBlobClient(request.getFileName()).getBlobName();
        String sasToken = generateSasToken(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY, CONTAINER_NAME, blobName, permission, expiryTime);
        String url = String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s?%s", STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, CONTAINER_NAME, request.getFileName(), sasToken);
        GetMediaUploadCredResponse res = GetMediaUploadCredResponse.newBuilder()
                .setMediaId(blobName)
                .setUploadCredentialUrl(url)
                .build();
        response.onNext(res);
        response.onCompleted();
    }

    private static String generateSasToken(String accountName, String accountKey, String containerName, String blobName, BlobSasPermission permission, OffsetDateTime expiryTime) {
        String sasToken = null;
        try {
            String signedPermissions = permission.toString();
            String signedStart = OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
            String signedExpiry = expiryTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
            String canonicalizedResource = String.format("/blob/%s/%s/%s", accountName, containerName, blobName);
            String signedVersion = "2020-12-06";

            String stringToSign = signedPermissions + "\n" +
                    signedStart + "\n" +
                    signedExpiry + "\n" +
                    canonicalizedResource + "\n" +
                    "\n" + // signedKeyObjectId
                    "\n" + // signedKeyTenantId
                    "\n" + // signedKeyStart
                    "\n" + // signedKeyExpiry
                    "\n" + // signedKeyService
                    "\n" + // signedKeyVersion
                    "\n" + // signedAuthorizedUserObjectId
                    "\n" + // signedUnauthorizedUserObjectId
                    "\n" + // signedCorrelationId
                    "\n" + // signedIP
                    "https\n" + // signedProtocol
                    signedVersion + "\n" +
                    "\n" + // signedResource
                    "\n" + // signedSnapshotTime
                    "\n" + // signedEncryptionScope
                    "\n" + // rscc
                    "\n" + // rscd
                    "\n" + // rsce
                    "\n" + // rscl
                    "\n"; // rsct

            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(accountKey), "HmacSHA256"));
            String signature = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            sasToken = String.format("sv=%s&st=%s&se=%s&sr=b&sp=%s&sig=%s",
                    signedVersion, signedStart, signedExpiry, permission.toString(), URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sasToken;
    }
```

And running the CURL command:

```
curl -X PUT \
  -T ~/Downloads/gfx100s_sample_04_thum-1.jpg \
  -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" \
  -H "x-ms-meta-name: example" \
  "<URL-with sas token>"
```

gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:124d92c4-101e-001e-189f-6157cc000000
Time:2023-03-28T18:02:50.6977457Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>%
```

But I followed the Signature fields from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#version-2020-12-06-and-later). So why am I still getting the error?

**Update 3:**

```
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING).buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME);

        OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(30);
        BlobClient blobClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME)
                .getBlobClient(request.getFileName());
        BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true).setWritePermission(true);
        BlobServiceSasSignatureValues sasValues = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permission);
        String sasToken = blobClient.generateSas(sasValues);

        String blobName = containerClient.getBlobClient(request.getFileName()).getBlobName();
        log.info(sasToken);
        String url = String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s?%s", STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, CONTAINER_NAME, request.getFileName(), sasToken);
        GetMediaUploadCredResponse res = GetMediaUploadCredResponse.newBuilder()
                .setMediaId(blobName)
                .setUploadCredentialUrl(url)
                .build();
```

Error:

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your first code snippet you are actually generating a valid SAS:

```json
{
    "uploadCredentialUrl": "sv=2021-10-04&spr=https%2Chttp&se=2023-03-24T13%3A36%3A38Z&sr=b&sp=w&sig=JUXXe1Qi13VWipgFWzx70mTOsVqadQCjmIF%2BxRl14cs%3D",
    "httpsHeaders": {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    "mediaId": "0ae4a0c5-167d-4a32-9752-0ad0d2b67e66.JPEG"
}
```

You mentioned that `uploadCredentialUrl` doesn't seem to be a valid URL and you are right because in fact you are receiving a SAS token.

A SAS token is composed by a series of [query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#construct-a-user-delegation-sas) that should be appended to the URL of the resource for which it should be applied.

You are creating a SAS for uploading a specific blob (you can create the SAS for different [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature)); it means that you need to provide the URL for the blob resource you want to create and append to that obtained SAS token.

Your `curl` command looks fine indeed, just be sure of using the right SAS token:

```
curl -X PUT -T ~/Downloads/gfx100s_sample_04_thum-1.jpg -H "x-ms-date: $(date -u)" "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container name>/myimage.jpg?<received SAS token>"
```

Please, consider review the [Put Blob REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=shared-access-signatures) for detailed information about the headers you can specify.

[This related page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/performing-simple-blob-storage-rest-api-operations-using-curl/ba-p/3302552) offers guidance as well.

Finally, you are trying generating the signature yourself, and the process is well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#specify-the-signature) but it is common to receive errors related to signature mismatch: if possible, prefer the Azure SDK for the specific programming language instead.

Comment: Hi, I have followed the docs provided and updated the code. Can you please check where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @Arnob. Please, instead of trying implementing your own `generateSas` functionally, could you try `BlobServiceSasSignatureValues`and `blobClient.generateSas` instead? As I told, it is always advisable to use the methods and functionally provided by the Azure SDK itself. Please, could you try?

Comment: Thanks @jccampanero for bearing with me. I have used `BlobServiceSasSignatureValues` and `blobClient.generateSas` as per your recommendation.

Comment: I just checked again and the final code snippet is working fine. I will post the entire thing as an answer and mark yours as correct one. Although I can't access the blob(image) from portal. But atleast it's there. I guess I have to create a SAS token every time I need to see it(?).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Arnob. That is nice, I am very happy to hear that you were able to upload the file in the end, and that the answer was helpful. Regarding your question, do you mean the Azure portal? Accessing the image from the Azure portal Web console? If that is the caso, no, you don't need to create a SAS token for accessing the blob, typically you connect to the Azure portal with certain user, with certain identity: if that identity has the right permissions it should be able to see and, in general, interact with the storage account object without further problem.

Comment: It's okay. And I was talking about how can user access their uploaded media after uploading. I probably didn't send the right headers to make the uploaded media public or something. Do I need to attach SAS tokens each time the user clicks on the resource URL?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Arnob. It depends on your application. You can for instance use a SAS in your app for example to list the images a user can see, and even download or present a preview of such images reusing the same SAS, without exposing it to the user; or you can generate a download URL for every image a user ca download, it depends. I search the web for examples that could help you: please, see for instance [this question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/252303/sas-url-to-display-in-browser-rather-than-download), it is for .net but I think it could be of help.

Comment: Thanks once again jccampenaro for helping so much. I will study more on the subject and will update my answer with updated code.

Comment: You are very welcome @Arnob. Please, don't hesitate to contact me again if you need further help.

Answer (score 3):

@jccampanero helped quite a lot. So thanks!

Here is the actual piece of code that worked:

```
    public String generatePresignedUrl {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING).buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME);

        OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(30);
        BlobClient blobClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME)
                .getBlobClient(request.getFileName());
        BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true).setWritePermission(true);
        BlobServiceSasSignatureValues sasValues = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permission);
        String sasToken = blobClient.generateSas(sasValues);

        String blobName = containerClient.getBlobClient(request.getFileName()).getBlobName();
        log.info(sasToken);
        String url = String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s?%s", STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, CONTAINER_NAME, request.getFileName(), sasToken);
        return url;
    }
```

and the curl command:

```
curl -X PUT -T <file-location> -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" "<resource-url with SAS token>"
```

Notice the `x-ms-blob-type`.

Resources that helped:

1. [String to sign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#version-2020-12-06-and-later) [if you want to do create the token manually]
2. [Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=shared-access-signatures#request-headers-all-blob-types)